# SqlCommand with both DECLARE and UPDATE

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

We have a legacy database where some ID lists are stored as a coma-separated strings. I need to replace one of that IDs to some other value.

To be more specific, the table of interest contains a column with values like "1,2,42,100". Note that this is a list of IDs, that is coma-separated. [I know that is not the best solution, but it was done before us in the middle of last century.]

For that I have a query, tested in SQL Server:

```
declare @w nvarchar(252)
update TableName
  set @w = replace(',' + ColumnName + ',', ',@oldName,', ',@newName,'), ColumnName = substring(@w, 2, len(@w) - 2)
```

This works in SQL Management studio, but translating this directly to C# code  does not produce any result:

```
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandTimeout = Connection.Instance.ConnectionTimeout;
    command.Connection.Open();
    command.CommandText = @"
        declare @w nvarchar(252);
        update TableName
            set @w = replace(',' + ColumnName + ',', ',@oldName,', ',@newName,'), ColumnName = substring(@w, 2, len(@w) - 2)
        <where clause here of course>;";

    SqlParameter param = command.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@newName";
    param.Value = newName;
    command.Parameters.Add(param);

    param = command.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@oldName";
    param.Value = oldName;
    command.Parameters.Add(param);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command.Connection.Close();
}
```

The question is a) why it does not give an error or desired result in C# and b) how to fix that?

Comment: I assume you have a dev copy of the table. What about removing the where clause and check if all entries have been updated? That way, you'll know if the issue comes from the where clause or not

Comment: Yes - I use the development DB. But I have tested the where clause in SQL Management Studio -- it worked there. Will try removing it anyway.

Comment: Update: Tested with no WHERE clause in C#, the update still seems not happening.

Comment: Does that assumed order of setting a variable first then using that for the following column actually work? I'd be wary of that myself and would just combine those two parts. That would also put it all into a single statement which might also help.

Comment: before execute it try Console.WriteLine(command.CommandText); compare with this from Sql Management Studio

Comment: @TomC: Do you mean getting rid of the @w temp variable and calling REPLACE twice, first in SUBSTRING, then in LEN? Or is there maybe a better way of doing what I am doing?

Comment: I might be wrong, but your `@newName` parameter may be overwritten by the old one. Can you give it a try to use a SqlParameter param2 for  `@oldName` ?

Comment: @Cid: No, I create a new object for each parameter, by using C# new (edit: actually it calls factory method CreateParameter, but this should not matter). This effectively creates a new "box" for the oldName, and forgets about the newName parameter (after putting it into the collection of the parameters).

Comment: I dont know if it would make any difference doing it without the @w. You could obviously do it inline, doing the replace twice. Just thinking of what I would try when trying to troubleshoot. Also maybe add the parameters into the original command string and call without parameters. Depends if you just want to get it to work or want to know why.

Comment: Sorry to insist, but I'd like to be sure about it :) `foreach (SqlParameter p in command.Parameters) { Debug.WriteLine(p.ParameterName + " = " + p.Value); }` result ?

Comment: @Cid: As expected,
@ newName = AGT
@ oldName = AG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all who helped! I found the answers.

Turns out that the C# and MSSQL do not inject the named parameters into the SQL string **if they are inside quotes**. That was exactly my case. I also was a bit wrong saying that "it works in SQL Management studio". I tested without the `@newName` and `@oldName` and instead hardcoding the corresponding values into the query.

So my working SQL query was indeed:

```
declare @w nvarchar(252)
update TableName
  set @w = replace(',' + ColumnName + ',', ',42,', ',101,'), ColumnName = substring(@w, 2, len(@w) - 2)
```

I tried the exact query (with defined @`newName` and @`oldName` from the SQL Studio, and it did not work as well.

So the working query would be:

```
declare @oldName nvarchar(250)='42'
declare @newName nvarchar(250)='101'
declare @w nvarchar(252)
update RoleMap
  set @w = replace(',' + Argument + ',', ','+@oldName+',', ','+@newName+','), Argument = substring(@w, 2, len(@w) - 2)
```

Note that the named parameters are now concatenated with the comma chars, not inside the strings with the commas.